# Linked list variation

Tags: c, linked-list

I am in a bit of a pickle. I have a variation of a linked list where not only do the nodes contain a value, but also each node will have a flag declaring whether it is a valid node or not (1 is valid; 0 is invalid). I have some functions that I am having difficulty with. I have deleteLast which deletes the last valid node, or in other words, clears the valid flag to 0. Bear in mind the last valid node might not be the last node; I was hoping countNodes would of use here. deleteValue 'deletes' first valid node with specified value. restoreValue restores the first 'deleted' node with specified value. lastly, compact makes a new list of valid nodes only in reverse order of the old list. deleteLast is the function I'm having most difficulty with. Any feedback on that function or any of the other functions will be of great help. Here's some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    struct Node *link;
    int value;
    int valid;
}

int countNodes (Node *ptrToFirst){
    int count=0;
    if(ptrToFirst==NULL){
        return 0;
}
else{
    while(ptrToFirst!=NULL){
        if(ptrToFirst->valid==1)
            count++;
            ptrToFirst=ptrToFirst->link;
    }
}
int deleteLast(Node *ptrToFirst){
    Node p;
    if(countNodes||ptrToFirst!=NULL){
        while(ptrToFirst!=NULL){
            ptrToFirst->link;
            if(ptrToFirst->valid==1)
            if(ptrToFirst->link==NULL){
        }
    }
}
else return 0;
}
int deleteValue(Node *ptrToFirst, int val){
    if(ptrToFirst==NULL){
        return 0;
}
    while(ptrToFirst!=NULL){
        if(ptrToFirst->value==val&&ptrToFirst->valid==1){
            ptrToFirst->valid=0;
            return 0;
        }
        else
            ptrToFirst=ptrToFirst->link;
    }
}
int restoreValue(Node *start, int val){
    if(start==NULL){
        return 0;
}
    while(start!=NULL){
        if(start->value==val&&start->valid==0)
            start->valid=1;
            return 1;
        else
            start=start->link;
    }
}
int compact(Node *old, **ptrToNewHeadPtr){
    Node temp;
    if(old!=NULL){
        while(old!=NULL){
            if(old->valid==1)
                temp=old;
                *ptrToNewHeadPtr=temp;
                 old=old->link;
        }
    return 1;
    }
else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please pick a specific problem.  Tell us what you expected and what actually happened.  We are not going to reverse engineer your wall of code.  Note: the posted code does not compile.  The compiler outputs 2 error messages.

Comment: ot: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) insert a blank line around each code block: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default`.  3) insert 2 or 3 blank lines between functions (be consistent)

Comment: regarding: `struct Node{
    struct Node *link;
    int value;
    int valid;
}`  This is missing the final semicolon `;`.

Comment: regarding: `int countNodes (Node *ptrToFirst){`  this is not the correct syntax.  The posted code has not defined a type `Node`  Rather, it has defined a type: `struct Node`.  So this function signature should be: `int countNodes (struct Node *ptrToFirst){`  This also applies to every instance of a `Node` in the posted code.

Comment: regarding; ` while(ptrToFirst!=NULL){
        if(ptrToFirst->valid==1)
            count++;
            ptrToFirst=ptrToFirst->link;
    }`  The `if` statement does not 'guard' both of the following statements.   In general, do not skip optional enclosing braces '{' and '}'

Comment: regarding: `int compact( struct Node *old, **ptrToNewHeadPtr){`  The second parameter is missing a 'type`

Comment: regarding: `if(old->valid==1)
                temp=old;
                *ptrToNewHeadPtr=temp;
                 old=old->link;`  see my prior comment about always including the braces.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: insert an appropriate space inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: regarding: `if(start->value==val&&start->valid==0)
            start->valid=1;
            return 1;`  See my prior comment about always including the braces '{' and '}'

Comment: OT:  regarding this kind of statement: `while(old!=NULL)`  This can be simplified to `while( old )`

Comment: regarding: `if(ptrToFirst->valid==1) if(ptrToFirst->link==NULL)`  This has a dangling `if()` statement. and really needs the braces for clarity

Comment: There are plenty more problems with the syntax of the code.  Please correct all of them, then repost